# $G =(V,E)$ is $k$-connected ($k \geq 2$), prove that for every subset $S \subseteq V $, |S|=k there exists a cycle in $G$ that goes through all of $S$

Tags: graph-theory, connectedness

I thought of starting from the Menger theorem which says that between every two vertices $u$ and $v$ there are $k$-edge disjoint graphs. So I think if I look at $G$ without the subset $S$ then I have $k$ paths from $S$ to $V-S$. I know for a fact that there has to be a cycle because $k \geq 2$ and between $u$ and $v$ there are at least two paths and they form a cycle. Now I was thinking about looking at $u\in S$ and $v\in V-S$. At this point I get stuck ...

Comment: yes, you're right!